# Find the Equation of the Plane Containing the Point $ (2, 3, -2)$ and the Line$\frac{ x-1}{6} =\frac{ y+1}{2} = z-3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

A certain plane contains the point $P=(2, 3, -2)$ and the line $\frac{ x-1}{6} =\frac{ y+1}{2} = z-3$.

I know that to find the equation of a plane I must have a point and a vector normal to that point.

Is $(6, 2, 1)$ the right normal vector?

If so then, the plane eq: $6(x-2) + 2(y-3) +(z+2) = 0$

Am I missing something?

This question was part of a previous examination in my university.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! :) A tip: put your problem statement in the body of the question too, not just in the title. In any case, what do you mean by $P(2,3,-2)$?

Comment: You would get the complete intuition about this question by looking at Example 1 on this page. http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/EqnsOfLines.aspx

Comment: Hi. Thanks! I will take your suggestion. (2,3,-2) are points on the plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the line contains the points $Q=(1, -1, 3)$ and $R=(7, 1, 4)$. Verify that $P$ does not lie on the given line, so using these three non-collinear points we can determine the normal vector to this plane. We have $$(\vec{Q}-\vec{P})\times(\vec{R}-\vec{P})=(-1, -4, 5)\times(5, -2, 6)=\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{i} &\mathbf{j} &\mathbf{k} \\ -1 & -4 & 5 \\ 5 & -2 & 6 \end{pmatrix}=(-14,31,22).$$ This is the desired normal vector for your plane, due to the nature of the cross product. Hence, the desired plane is $-14(x-2) + 31(y-3) + 22(z+2) = 0$, or $-14x+31y+22z=21$, of course assuming I did my arithmetic correctly.

Comment: Where did you get Q and R from?

Comment: Try to make each term of the symmetric equation for the line equal to $0$ and $1$ respectively. Points $Q$ and $R$ achieve this.

Comment: @tc1729: a small point of contention is that $-4\cdot 6 - (-2)\cdot 5 = -24+10 = -14$. Your final answer should be some equation in the form $-14x+31y+22z = -14(2)+31(3)+22(-2) = 21$. You still get an upvote though.

Comment: @ChrisK Thanks, evidently I made a mistake in transcribing from my scratch work to stackexchange.

Comment: It all makes sense now. I thought that I was already given a normal vector with just the given symmetric equation of a line. Thanks everyone for making this clear.